# Link cell value to form combobox value

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

Might be easy, but how do I link a form comboxbox value to a cell or a dropdown list of cells ? In my case a 1 or 2 dimensional with month - year or month txt - month nr value or array needs to be linked to a form combobox.

The result should be that when I change the form combobox value it also updates the excel cell or cells (the 2 cells combination above) and also the other way around, when I update the cell or cells, it also updates the form combobox value.

Atm, I only have it one way, from form combobox to value by using the built in sub.

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List").Range("G2").value = Form1.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When I change the form combobox month, it also changes the cell value for example from May to June. What I am trying to achieve is the reverse to also be true, changing the cell value from May to June should update the form combobox value to June. Basically, wherever the user changes the month cell or combobox, it should be reflected in the other place too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around, I have found the answer to be in the `Combobox` properties window, `ControlSource`. I put there in my case `'List'!G2` and combined with the `Sub ComboBox1_Change()` it updates the month both ways.